# VBA to reference the same cell even after the addition or deletion of rows & Columns

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using `VBA` code to write to cells in excel. For eg.

```
Range("C3") = code
```

Or

```
Cells(3,3) = code
```

If a row is inserted in the sheet, the code does then not update accordingly and would still write to `Range("C3")` etc. So the code then writes to the incorrect cell.

Is there a better way I can structure my code so it will update accordingly? Perhaps using a table instead of cells?

Comment: Put a reference to the cell object into variable prior to any rows could be inserted `Set mycell = Range("C3")`, then just update the cell value `mycell.Value = code`. Note, if the cell will be deleted, then the reference gives an error.

Comment: @omegastripes .. I think the row is inserted from the FrontEnd, Rather than any code.

Comment: If you were inserting the cell value manually, how would you know where it should go (eg. would you look for column headers etc)?  You can mimic that process using VBA.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes sorry I meant insert row by the front end user as @Mikku mentioned, not by the code, but the same issue would arise. I've resulted running a for loop to search for a string in the column, that way it doesnt matter what the row is, just have to ensure the entire range is searched over

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to used [Named Ranges](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64). You can define a Named Range in Formula Tab by clicking on Name Manager.

Then you will write.

```
Range("Name of the Range") = code
```

My believe is that named ranges update automatically when a row or column is inserted, so your code will print the value in the correct cell.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, good idea. I ended up defining the column filled with values as a range, then use a for loop to search for the defined string. That way it doesnt matter what row it is in aslong as the name and string doesnt change (Using a Named Range will probably be better for that exact reason).

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
        Set WS = ActiveSheet
            With WS
                LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row       'Determine the last row number with data in it for column B
                    For Each acell In .Range("B1:B" & LastRow)       'Defines the search range from B1 to last row

                        If acell.Value = "String Searched For" Then
                            'Do stuff based on found cell location
                        End If

                        If acell.Value = "String Searched For#2" Then
                            'Do stuff based on found cell location#2
                        End If
                    Next
            End With
```